# Formatting returned Strings?

Tags: java, string, methods, return

I'm really new to coding and just got assigned my first coding homework involving methods and returns. I managed to struggle through and end up with this, which I'm pretty proud of, but I'm not quite sure it's right. Along with that, my return statements are all on the same lines instead of formatted how my teacher says they should be ("n is a perfect number", then the line below says "factors: x y z", repeated for each perfect number. Below are the exact instructions plus what it outputs. Anything will help!

*Write a method (also known as functions in C++) named isPerfect that takes in one parameter named number, and return a String containing the factors for the number that totals up to the number if the number is a perfect number.  If the number is not a perfect number, have the method return a null string (do this with a simple:  return null; statement).
Utilize this isPerfect method in a program that prompts the user for a maximum integer, so the program can display all perfect numbers from 2 to the maximum integer*

```
286 is perfect.Factors: 1 2 3 1 2 4 7 14
```

It should be

```
6 is perfect
Factors: 1 2 3
28 is perfect
Factors: 1 2 4 7 14
```

```java
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in) ;
        System.out.print("Enter max number: ") ;
        int max = input.nextInt() ;
        String result = isPerfect(max) ;
        System.out.print(result) ;
    }

    public static String isPerfect(int number) {
        String factors = "Factors: " ;
        String perfect = " is perfect." ;
        for (int test = 1; number >= test; test++) {
            int sum = 0 ;
            for (int counter = 1; counter <= test/2; counter++) {
                if (test % counter == 0) {
                    sum += counter ;
                }
            }
            if (sum == test) {
                perfect = test + perfect ;
                for (int counter = 1; counter <= test/2; counter++) {
                    if (test % counter == 0) {
                        factors += counter + " " ;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        return perfect + factors ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please have your IDE indent your code properly before posing it to Stack Overflow. It means something to readability, and you want people to (be able to) read your code.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you could do:

1. Firstly, you do not need two loops to do this. You can run one loop till number and keep checking if it's divisible by the iterating variable. If it is, then add it to a variable called sum.
   Example:

.

```
 factors = []; //this can be a new array or string, choice is yours
    sum=0;
    for(int i=1; i<number; i++){
        if(number % i == 0){
            sum += i;
            add the value i to factors variable.
        }
    }
```

2. after this loop completes, check if sum == number, the if block to return the output with factors, and else block to return the output without factors or factors = null(like in the problem statement)
3. In your return answer add a newline character between perfect and the factors to make it look like the teacher's output.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the solution below:

```
public String isPerfect(int number) {
    StringBuilder factors = new StringBuilder("Factors: ");
    StringBuilder perfect = new StringBuilder(" is perfect.");
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            sum += i;
            factors.append(" " + i);
        }
    }
    if (sum == number) {
        return number + "" + perfect.append(" \n" + factors);
    }
    return number + " is not perfect";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep separate variables for your template bits for the output and the actual output that you are constructing. So I suggest that you don’t alter `factors` and `perfect` and instead declare one more variable:

```
    String result = "";
```

Now when you’ve found a perfect number, add to the result like this:

```
            result += test + perfect + '\n' + factors;
            for (int counter = 1; counter <= test/2; counter++) {
                if (test % counter == 0) {
                    result += counter + " ";
                }
            }
            result += '\n';
```

I have also inserted some line breaks, `'\n'`. Then of course return the `result` from your method:

```
    return result;
```

With these changes your method returns:

```
6 is perfect.
Factors: 1 2 3 
28 is perfect.
Factors: 1 2 4 7 14
```

**Other tips**

1. While your program gives the correct output, your method doesn’t follow the specs in the assignment. It was supposed to check only one number for perfectness. Only your main program should iterate over numbers to find all perfect numbers up to the max.
2. You’ve got your condition turned in an unusual way here, which makes it hard for me to read:

   ```
   for (int test = 1; number >= test; test++) {
   ```

   Prefer

   ```
   for (int test = 1; test <= number; test++) {
   ```
3. For building strings piecewise learn to use a `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`.

**Link**

[Java StringBuilder class](https://www.javatpoint.com/StringBuilder-class) on Javapoint Tutorials, with examples.